# Quiver representations over any commutative ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, quivers

I'm reading a paper of Aidan Schofield "General Representations of Quivers" and he defines quiver representation over any commutative ring. See the below image.[image]

Towards the end, he has this representation $R_p\bigotimes\Lambda$ of the quiver $Q$. My questions are:

> 1. is the tensor product taken over the field $\mathbb{K}$?
> 2. what are the $\Lambda$-modules assigned at each vertex and what are the $\Lambda$-module morphisms assigned for each arrow for this representation $R_p\bigotimes\Lambda$?

(Here, $R_p$ is the usual representation of the quiver $Q$ where for each vertex you have a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and for each arrow you have a $\mathbb{K}$-linear map between the corresponding vector spaces)

Comment: Cross-posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510076/quiver-representation-over-any-commutative-ring). Please don't post the same question on both sites at the same time, particularly without linking to the version on the other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that $\Lambda$ should be a $k$-algebra and the tensor product should be over $k$. Then $R_p\otimes_k \Lambda$ makes sense as a representation of $Q$ over $\Lambda$, or equivalently as a $\Lambda Q$-module.

Namely, the Grassmannian $\mathcal{Gr}(R_p,\alpha)$ doesn't make sense as a scheme, but only as a $k$-scheme, determined by a functor from $k$-algebras to sets. In this case the functor sends a $k$-algebra $\Lambda$ to the set of summands of $R_p \otimes_k \Lambda$ of rank $\alpha$ (i.e., localizing at any maximal ideal of $\Lambda$, the projective $\Lambda$-module corresponding to a vertex $v$ should give a free module over the localization of rank $\alpha(v)$).

Comment: Sorry, but localization part is not clear to me. Why are we localizing at a maximal ideal? Also, do we know what the $\Lambda-$ module map for each arrow of the quiver look like, given that we know the representation $R_p$?

Comment: I should have said prime ideals. If $\Lambda$ is a commutative ring, the rank of a finitely generated projective $\Lambda$-module $P$ is defined to be $n$ if for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\Lambda$, the module $P_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is free of rank $n$ over $\Lambda_\mathfrak{p}$. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133333/rank-of-projective-module

Comment: For the second question: $R = R_p$ is a representation of the quiver over $k$, so given by a vector space $R(v)$ for each vertex $v$ and a linear map $R(a):R(v)\to R(w)$ for each arrow $a:v\to w$. For a commutative $k$-algebra $\Lambda$, the representation $R\otimes_k \Lambda$ is given by the free $\Lambda$-module $R(v)\otimes_k \Lambda$ for each vertex and the $\Lambda$-module map $R(a)\otimes_k \Lambda:R(v) \otimes_k \Lambda \to R(w) \otimes_k \Lambda $ for each arrow $a:v\to w$.